# twig and quote character

Tags: symfony, twig

in a twig template I want to insert javascript text like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    {{ "var applicationBundleName = '" ~ application_bundle_name ~ "';" | raw}}
</script>
```

When the html is rendered, I have this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var applicationBundleName = &#039;MyBundle_name&#039;;
</script>
```

While rendering the quotes are replaces by their html entities => javascript error

How can I say not to remplace special characters by their codes ? or maybe there is a nicer way to do that..

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to quote only the twig variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var applicationBundleName = "{{ application_bundle_name|raw }}";
</script>
```

I'm not sure but I think that if the variable is a string you don't need to use de `raw` filter